# Intercept search engine with an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I enter something in my browser search bar, and it is not an URL, he is polite enough to enter that word into the default search engine and send me the results.

Can I prevent that redirection and perform some logic on that string that I have typed?

For example, I enter `1233test` in the bar. It is not a URL and I want to check if that string contains numbers `123` in it, and if it does, prevent the search engine redirection and do something more, else, do the normal redirection. (Logic on the string)

What I have tried is the Omnibox solution, but the caveat with it is that I need to have a keyword in order to activate it.

manifest.json

```
...
"omnibox": { "keyword" : "--" },
...
```

What I have also tried is experimentation with `webRequest` API but everyone the listeners there working only when the proper URL is made (Redirection to search engine), but not sooner.

Expectations:

When I enter `123--everything else`, the extension needs to recognize that it is not an URL, and see if there is string `123` in it. If there is, prevent redirection.

Comment: If the user didn't disable "prediction service" in browser settings, you should be able to see the requests to the default search engine in chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest in Chrome, from which you can decode the typed text in the query parameter.

Comment: @wOxxOm Uh huh, I see. So, in order for the user to use my extension, he would have to do that manually? Extension can't disable `prediction service` on the behalf of the user?

Comment: Do manually what? The hack I described works if the user *didn't* change the default mode.

Comment: Ok, but if I go and manually enter `google.com/q=123blabla` the extension would still trigger. Correct? That would classify as intentional page visit, not help from a search engine, and I don't want that.

Comment: Typing manually would perform multiple queries of the text incrementally like goo, google, google, and so on, which you can detect. Only pasting an URL would cause a confusion.